# a problem about convergence in $L^{P}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I need a small certain hint for solving this problem please.

Problem: 
Let 
$(f_{n})_{n} $
be a bounded sequence in 
$ L^{3}(\mathbb{R}), $
such that 
$ f_{n}\to f $
in
$ L^{\frac{3}{2}}(\mathbb{R}). $
Prove that 
$ f_{n}\to f $
in
$ L^{2}(\mathbb{R}). $

Comment: where is $f$ ? in $L^3$ ?

Comment: I checked the problem again. It is accurately what I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to holder inequality:$$\int|f||g|dx\leq\left(\int|f|^pdx\right)^{1/p}\left(\int|g|^qdx\right)^{1/q}$$
So if  $p= 3$ and $q= \frac{3}{2}$, we get 
$$\int|f_n-f||f_n-f|dx\leq\left(\int|f_n-f|^{3}dx\right)^{1/3}\left(\int|f_n-f|^{3/2}dx\right)^{2/3}.$$
Since $f_n$ is bounded in $L^3(\mathbb{R})$, $\Vert f_n-f\Vert_{L^3(\mathbb{R})}(\leq\Vert f_n\Vert+\Vert f\Vert)$ is bounded too.
In the meantime, $f_n\to f$ in $L^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$, so $$\left(\int|f_n-f|^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}dx\to0 \quad as \quad n\to\infty$$
All in all, we'll see$$\int|f_n-f||f_n-f|dx\to0 \quad as \quad n\to\infty$$

P.S. Thanks to @zhw.

since $f_n\to f$ in $L^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$ , then we have $f_n\xrightarrow{m} f$ in $\mathbb{R}$. According to Riesz theorem, there is a subsequence of $\{f_n\}_n$, named as $\{f_{n_k}\}_k$, that converges to $f$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.

Due to Fatou's lemma $$\int|f|^3dx=\int \varliminf|f_{n_k}|^3dx\leq \varliminf\int|f_{n_k}|^3dx<\infty$$

Comment: But why $\|f\|_{L^3}$ would be finite ?

Comment: The OP wanted a small hint, not the whole solution.

Comment: @Surb Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: @zhw.: Oh yes ! Very well found :-)

Comment: @zhw.: Wow that's a good way.

Comment: A hint was enough for me. Any way thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write $f=|f_n-f|.$ Also your proof that $f\in L^3$ is incorrect.

Comment: @zhw.: I've corrected them. Thank you for your reminder. Could you check them for me?

Comment: This is false: since $f_n\to f$ in $L^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$ , then we have $f_n\to f \ a.e. in\  \mathbb{R}$. But Fatou's lemma still holds; can you see why?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: That's really a terrible mistake. Thank you for that! I've tried to correct that, can you check for me?

Comment: Looks good now!